# How can I put my members container in the middle of the page?

Tags: html, css

So, I have got a members page and I have made it responsive (for phones and etc) but I have no clue how I can put it in the middle of the page 100% of the time when it isn't in mobile view. Please someone help me out here's what i've got:

**HTML**

```
        <div class="members-container">
            <div class="members-header">
                <h1>Our Members</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="sub-container">
                <div class="teams">
                    <img src="assets/imgs/tcsmasked.jpg" alt="">
                    <div class="members-name"><a href="https://www.tcsmasked.maskednet.org">TCSMasked</a></div>
                    <div class="members-label">Founder</div>
                    <div class="social-links">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="teams">
                    <img src="assets/imgs/pieandstuff.png" alt="">
                    <div class="members-name"><a href="https://www.pie.maskednet.org">Pie and Stuff</a></div>
                    <div class="members-label">Owner</div>
                    <div class="social-links">
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                        <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

**CSS**

```
.members-container {
    text-align: center;
}
.members-header {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.members-header h1 {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
}
.teams {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    display: grid;
}
.teams img {
    display: flex;
    width: 220px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 220px;
}
.members-name {
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.members-name a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.members-name a:hover {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}
.members-label {
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #888;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.social-links {
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.social-links a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    transition: .4s;
}
.social-links a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.social-links a i {
    color: #000000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {
    .teams {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
    body {
        overflow: scroll
    }
}
```

I have tried a couple things I have found on stack overflow however nothing has fixed it. It is probably my terrible coding. Please can someone help me put my members in the middle of the page instead of it just being stuck at the top of the page, Thanks :D

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it. Here are the codes I added:

```
/* Will work until the images are being displayed one in each column. If you want you can simply 
change the min-width from the media query */

@media screen and (min-width: 588px){
    .sub-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50vh - 217px);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}
```

```css
    .members-container {
        text-align: center;
    }
.members-header {
    color: #ffffff;
    font-size: 20px;
}
.members-header h1 {
    font-family: 'Orbitron', sans-serif;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.sub-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    justify-content: center;
    position: absolute;
    top: calc(50vh - 217px);
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
}

/* Will work until images are being displayed one in each column */
@media screen and (min-width: 588px){
    .sub-container {
        position: absolute;
        top: calc(50vh - 217px);
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
    }
}

.teams {
    text-align: center;
    margin: 15px;
    padding: 15px;
    transition: 0.4s;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    background: #fff;
    border-radius: 15px;
    margin-top: 4rem;
    display: grid;
}
.teams img {
    display: flex;
    width: 220px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    height: 220px;
}
.members-name {
    margin-top: -5px;
    padding: 12px;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 30px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.members-name a {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
    transition: all .5s ease;
}
.members-name a:hover {
    color: #5c5c5c;
}
.members-label {
    margin-top: -15px;
    font-style: italic;
    color: #888;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.social-links {
    margin-top: 15px;
    -webkit-touch-callout: none;
    -webkit-user-select: none;
    -khtml-user-select: none;
    -moz-user-select: none;
    -ms-user-select: none;
    user-select: none;
}
.social-links a {
    display: inline-block;
    font-size: 25px;
    height: 30px;
    width: 30px;
    transition: .4s;
}
.social-links a:hover {
    transform: scale(1.2);
}
.social-links a i {
    color: #000000;
}
@media screen and (max-width: 823px) {
    .teams {
        max-width: 100%;
    }
}
@media screen and (max-width: 530px) {
    body {
        overflow: scroll
    }
}
```

```html
<body>
    <div class="members-container">
        <div class="members-header">
            <h1>Our Members</h1>
        </div>
        <div class="sub-container">
            <div class="teams">
                <img src="assets/imgs/tcsmasked.jpg" alt="">
                <div class="members-name"><a href="https://www.tcsmasked.maskednet.org">TCSMasked</a></div>
                <div class="members-label">Founder</div>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="teams">
                <img src="assets/imgs/pieandstuff.png" alt="">
                <div class="members-name"><a href="https://www.pie.maskednet.org">Pie and Stuff</a></div>
                <div class="members-label">Owner</div>
                <div class="social-links">
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
                    <a href="#"><i class="fa fa-github"></i></a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```